# In Shor's factorization algorithm for $N$, why can we always find $n$ such that $N^2\le 2^n\le 2N^2$?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, mathematics, shors-algorithm

This may be a silly question but at the start of Shor's algorithm to factorise a number $N$ we need to find a number $n$ such that 
$N^{2} \leq 2^{n} \leq 2N^{2}$
Why does such a number $n$ exist for any $N$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's represent $N^2$ as $2^a+b$, where $a$ is the greatest power of 2 that not exceeds $N^2$, and $b \ge 0$ (which is always possible to do - $a$ is just the number of bits in binary representation of $N^2$). Then $n = a+1$:

- $N^2 \le 2^{a+1}$, because otherwise $a$ would not be the greatest power of 2 that not exceeds $N^2$.
- $2^{a+1} \le 2N^2 = 2(2^a+b) = 2^{a+1} + 2b$, because $b \ge 0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $2^k$ is less than $x$, you can increase $k$ by 1 without exceeding $2x$. Because if $2^k < x$ then $2 \cdot 2^k < 2 \cdot x$ and so $2^{k+1} < 2x$. If you start at $k=0$ and keep incrementing, $2^k$ will eventually exceed $x$, and at that exact moment you stop; knowing that you didn't also exceed $2x$ and so have met both criteria.

Or you can just use a closed-form definition:

$k = \lceil \log_2 x \rceil$

Or, in the original variables:

$n = \lceil \log_2 N^2 \rceil$